# Does inline-block affect the clickability of links?

Tags: css

For quite a few sites, I have used the [CSS3 Bon Bon buttons](http://archive.simurai.com/lab/buttons/#) that allow buttons to be displayed with a 3D effect. I often use them for my `<a></a>` links.

Everything works fine except when `display: inline-block` is applied, it doesn't always seem to click correctly. Sometimes (but not always) you might have to click the button 3 or 4 times before it registers. Other times, the exact same button will click straight away. It seems to occur on all browsers and platforms.

Why is this and is there a solution? If I set it to `display block`, it works perfectly, but there are situations where `display:block` is not ideal.

JSFiddle ([Code](http://jsfiddle.net/big_smile/Y8wKd/1/)) ([Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/big_smile/Y8wKd/1/show/))

Comment: It seems to depend on where you click on the button, not how many times.

Comment: @AliGajani You can't click an element on its shadow. With this button it means you can't click on the 3D part of the it.

Comment: @dodo, I see. Is there a way to make the shadow clickable?

Comment: Which part do you define as the button? I see the button as the part where the cursor changes to the hand(not including shadow). Every time I click on it, the button disappears in the fiddle, I assume that's how it woks. So it worked 100% of the time on newest FF on OSX

Comment: @big_smile I don't think it makes sense for the shadow to be clickable since it is not part of the button

Comment: @big_smile I changed `inline-block` to `block` but it doesn't change the fact that `box-shadow` in not clickable.

Comment: So the answer to your question is no, inline-block does not affect the clickability

Comment: @Huangism I just tried it now: If you click on the words purchase (and not the shadow) so the button turns white, it didn't register the click. I tried it 8 times and it only clicked on 6 of them.

Comment: @big_smile which browser on which OS? on mac FF it's 10/10

Comment: @huangism on Mac OS Chrome, Mac Os Safari, Windows 8 Chrome and Ios6 Safari

Comment: @big_smile You are right, I just make a [test here](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/Y8wKd/5/) Open up the `console` and click on the button multiple times, the click event doesn't trigger sometimes if you click continuously.

Comment: @HashemQolami Thanks! Is there any way to fix it? Sometimes, it wont even triger if you click on the first time.

Comment: Try removing the position relative, I took it off and it seems to register the click every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that using display: block; may be filling in the extra unclickable space within your button, so when you switch to display: inline-block; the inline element neglects to fill the additional space.

Your example is very dense and hard to make out what is going on, given the CSS used to render the button. Don't suppose you could supply a pared-down version that would make it easier to see what's going on?

Comment: I don't think that's it, I click the button on the same spot every time, and sometimes it does not work in webkit browsers.

Comment: I tried stripping out all of the gradient/drop shadows, and the button seems to work just fine without them, so it looks like it is definitely tied to the attributes being applied to the element(gradients and shadows).

Answer (score 1):

Ok after debugging for awhile, I know what is causing it. I don't know why, some expert can try and explain this. In

```
.cta-primary:active, .cta-secondary:active
```

It contains

```
-webkit-transform: translateY(0.2em);
-moz-transform: translateY(0.2em);
-ms-transform: translateY(0.2em);
-o-transform: translateY(0.2em);
transform: translateY(0.2em);
```

I removed that and it works. Not sure why this would interfere but it does. Maybe because the translate moves the element for that active millisecond and the click does not actually hit the button but visually you can't really tell because it is too fast. If you replaced the 0.2em with 0, it will also work since it won't move the element. Hope this is what you are looking for.